# Expression on Func with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, nhibernate, delegates, expression, func

I am trying to write an expression that invokes a method that accepts more than one argument as an input and this expression acts as a where clause to the nhibernate queryover engine. Currently I am getting an error saying:

> System.Exception : Unrecognised method call: `` System.Func`3[[MyClass,
>   Assembly, Version=9.123.434, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=wjerkwr234],[System.Boolean, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=234234123]]:Boolean
>   Invoke(MyClass, Int32) ``

```
 Expression<Func<MyClass, int, bool>> restricton=
         (myClassObject, myNumber) => myClassObject.Property1== myNumber;

session
    .QueryOver<MyClass>()
    .Where(x =>x.Property2==1)
    .And(x=>restriction.Compile().Invoke(x, 2))
```

why am I using expression? Well that is a parameter to the function that generates the queryover statement and the condition there can change

Any idea what is wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the linq provider expects an Expression but you give it a Delegate because you use `Compile()`.

```
int myNumber = 5;
Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> restricton=
     myClassObject => myClassObject.Property1 == myNumber

session.QueryOver().Where(x => x.Property2 == 1).And(restriction)
```

Update: if it is only known when constructing the query

```
session.QueryOver().Where(x => x.Property2 == 1).And(CreateRestriction(2))

Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> CreateRestriction(int myNumber)
{
    return myClassObject => myClassObject.Property1 == myNumber;
}
```

Comment: firo the problem is that myNumber cannot be set when I am constructing the Expression and that is why I had it as a second paramter.. whats the solution then?